# Exception with saving and loading of LinearSVM model in Mllib

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-mllib

I want to use  linear SVM for classification. Here is the problem that I encounter while using Mllib. I am using CDH 5.4.4 and Spark 1.3 with MLlib dependency is specified as the following in my pom file:

```
<properties>
    <uber.jar.name>linearsvm.jar</uber.jar.name>
    <cdh.version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.4</cdh.version>
    <cdh.spark.version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.4</cdh.spark.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${cdh.spark.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
                <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Here is my code to train the model

```
def main() {

    val numIterations = 100

    // Run training algorithm to build the model
    val model = SVMWithSGD.train(training, numIterations)

    // Save the trained model
    model.save(spark,"mymodelpath")

}
```

Here is another class where I load that model

```
 def performScoring (test: RDD[LabeledPoint] ) {

   // load the saved model
    val savedModel = SVMModel.load(spark, "mymodelpath")

    savedModel.clearThreshold()

    // Compute raw scores on the test set.

    val scoreAndLabels = test.map { point =>
      val score = savedModel.predict(point.features)
      (score, point.label)
    }

    // Get evaluation metrics.

    val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(scoreAndLabels)
    val auROC = metrics.areaUnderROC()

    println("Area under ROC = " + auROC)

  }
```

Here is the exception that I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$class.firstAvailableClass(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$class.newJobContext(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.newJobContext(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.getJobContext(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.preSetup(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1057)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:954)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1290)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.impl.GLMClassificationModel$SaveLoadV1_0$.save(GLMClassificationModel.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMModel.save(SVM.scala:84)
    at LinearSVM$.main(LinearSVM.scala:32)
    at LinearSVM.main(LinearSVM.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: what's the version of spark-core you are using? what is the version of spark installed on your cluster? the issue might be there!

Comment: I have added those details to the original question.

Comment: Can you add the provided scope to your spark dependencies and try again?

Comment: Did not work, I got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils$
 at LinearSVM$.main(LinearSVM.scala:21)
 at LinearSVM.main(LinearSVM.scala)

Comment: How did you install your spark?